# How can I hide a partition (or prevent it from mounting)?

Tags: macos, partition

How can I hide a partition (or prevent it from mounting)? I want an effect similar to the recovery partition: it's completely undetectable outside of Disk Utility/the boot menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitions that are mounted in Mac OSX are generally present in the file /etc/fstab that is read upon boot. If you just comment out (i.e. put a # in front of it, and save the file) the line that referes to the drive you do not want to mount, it will not mount upon next boot.

**edit**
FYI. I am not sure which OSX you are on, but since OSX Lion the implementation of /etc/fstab has changed:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3582968?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: To make the most of the Q&A format on AskDifferent we prefer to have answers which stand on their own. So instead of having people read through a Apple Discussions thread guessing what exactly and which post you had in mind, can you please summarize the key items here? Or even better: add a sample fstab entry to your answer? (The asker is using 10.8 actually)